# C++ ASM IDA address patterns

Tags: c++, assembly

I am trying to write a pattern finder for a test application i made that uses Directx9, but i am having some issues with finding the correct start pattern.
The pointer i am trying to find is the IDIRECT3D9 device pointer.

```
unsigned long dwStartAddress = 0x14008613F, dwLen = ( 0x14008613F - 0x14008615D );

bool bDataCompare(const unsigned char* pData, const unsigned char* bMask, const char* szMask)
{
    for (; *szMask; ++szMask, ++pData, ++bMask)
        if (*szMask == 'x' && *pData != *bMask)
            return false;
    return (*szMask) == 0;
}

unsigned long dwFindPattern(unsigned char *bMask, char * szMask, unsigned long dw_Address = dwStartAddress, unsigned long dw_Len = dwLen)
{
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < dw_Len; i++)
        if (bDataCompare((unsigned char*)(dw_Address + i), bMask, szMask))
            return (unsigned long)(dw_Address + i);
    return 0;
}
```

Iv'e dug through the d3d9.h file and took a look at the sample projects for Microsoft DirectX SDK (August 2009) found here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23549

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb219676(v=vs.85).aspx Direct3DCreate9Ex checks if D3Dx9ex features are supported.

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174313(v=vs.85).aspx
Direct3DCreate9::CreateDevice returns the pointer

[image]

below i am making the assumption that i can start my address scan at 0x14008613F and end at ( 0x14008613F - 0x14008615D )

Also i am making the assumption that

```
jnz short loc_14008615E
mov [rbx+0E8h], eax
```

is the location for my device pointer that im looking for. with

```
[rbx+0E8h]
```

being the pointer returned from Direct3DCreate9::CreateDevice

I hope iv'e given enough information on this, as this is my first attempt at doing any real memory manipulation.

Edit:
incase its important here is my signature and mask:

```
DWORD  m_dwaddy = dwFindPattern((PBYTE)"\x00\x48\x8B\xF8", (char *)"?xxx");
```

Comment: Seems like an XY problem, what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Is your pattern scanner working or the pattern is incorrect?

Comment: The code works, my issue is finding the correct dwStartAddress and dwLen.

Comment: You can use SigMaker plugin by P4TR!CK that creates signatures for you, there should be a port for IDA 7.0

Comment: With the current values my application crashes because of memory issues with pData inside bDataCompare

Comment: Why not just make start address `0x00400000` and length `0x07FFFFFF`

Comment: @Konrad thanks iv'e heard of that, i wasn't sure who the developer was until now. So thanks :) maybe that will help me.

Comment: @Konrad i just tried those values and i got the same issue "the instruction at 0x%p referenced memory at 0xp. The memory could not be %s (c0000005)"

Comment: btw you can also hook `IDirect3D9::CreateDevice` and get your device this way.

Comment: That would definitely contribute to a better solution. im not sure i know exactly how to hook. ( i will be researching this right now )

Comment: without pattern scan : first hook `Direct3DCreate9`, it's an import so finding address is just a matter of `GetProcAddress(hModule, "Direct3DCreate9")`

Comment: from there you can use vtable hook and hook `CreateDevice` which is virtual function. You can find index by looking at the d3d9 headers.

Comment: There are many good libraries for hooking I'm sure you'll figure :)

Comment: Thanks @Konrad i think you pushed me in the right direction. I looked at some documentation and hooking looks fairly simple. I'll write the detour, and post an edit on my question :) thanks man